# How to get the active call time for call in twilio client with js?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I'm made an app which will make audio calls to twilio. The call was working fine now, I want to show the active call timer. How I can show that?

`Twilio.Device.incoming(_takeACall);`

Here, I'm calling one function which will handles the incoming call once the call was accepted I want to show the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twilio javascript client callback on call answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141528/twilio-javascript-client-callback-on-call-answer)